# Error while running h2o.deeplearning algorithm in R

Tags: r, h2o

I am facing an error while running this command in H2O Deep Learning in R:

```
model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = x, y = y, seed = 1234,
                          training_frame = as.h2o(trainDF),
                          nfolds = 3, 
                          stopping_rounds = 7, 
                          epochs = 400,
                          overwrite_with_best_model = TRUE,
                          activation = "Tanh",
                          input_dropout_ratio = .1,
                          hidden = c(10,10),
                          l1 = 6e-4,
                          loss = "automatic",
                          distribution = 'AUTO',
                          stopping_metric = "MSE")
```

ERROR as below:

> Error in h2o.deeplearning(x = x, y = y, seed = 1234, training_frame = as.h2o(trainDF),  : 
>     unused arguments (training_frame = as.h2o(trainDF), stopping_rounds = 7, overwrite_with_best_model = TRUE, distribution = "AUTO", stopping_metric = "MSE")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your specific error, but I was able to get the code to work on my end by updating `loss="automatic"` to `loss="Automatic"` (note that `loss` it is case sensitive).